# how to get the data out of a stored procedure when the data is a 'clob' on an IBMi using DB2?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2-400, java-stored-procedures

I am accessing a IBMi running DB2 from a java JVM. I have a stored procedure that returns a CLOB
and I want to access the clob from Java.

The sql for the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ZZSP (
IN fromjson VARCHAR(16000) CCSID 1208,
out tojson clob(10000000) CCSID 1208,
out last_id decimal(20, 0),
out sha VARCHAR(20) CCSID 1208,
out version VARCHAR(20) CCSID 1208)
LANGUAGE RPGLE
SPECIFIC ZZSP
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
COMMIT ON RETURN YES
EXTERNAL NAME 'ZZSP'
PARAMETER STYLE SQL;
```

The stored procedure can be accessed from 'run sql scripts' in IBMi client access solutions:

```
create variable MYCLOB5 clob(10000000) ccsid 1208;
CALL ZZSP ('{"returnStatus":" ","fetchKey":{"inp1":1,"seq1":2},"status":"X"}',myClob5,?,?,?);
values myClob5;
```

When I do this, the 'values myClob5' holds a json string that is almost identical to the passed in json string (because that's what the stored procedure does). I am thus assuming that the rpg code that this calls (also called ZZSP) is working.

However when I try and access this from java I run into a problem. I can use this code to get data out of a resultset, but not out of the statement. Prior to the call we have set up parameters in the callable statement:

```
void doit(CallableStatement s){ 
      cs.setString(1, json)
      cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.CLOB)
      cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.DECIMAL)
      cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR)
      cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR)
 // setup the statement with the sql 'call ZZSP(?,?,?,?,?)', and execute it
   
   val jsonOutClob = s.getClob(2)
   val json = jsonOutClob.getSubString(1, jsonOutClob.length().toInt)
   ...
}
```

While all the other data returned from the stored procedure (outParameters 3,4,5) return the correct value, the data in the clob is 'garbage': it doesn't look like a string to me. The data I expect is something like `'{"returnStatus":" ","fetchKey":{"inp1":1,"seq1":2},"status":"X"}'`, but the actual data is something like `'?zɕƿk??z?????????????⣁zտЀ'`. It's also interesting that the length of the clob is half the length of the expected string. The bytes in the returned string start with `List(3f, f1, 85, a3, a4, f1, 95, a2, a3, f1, a3, a4, a2, 7f, 7a, 7f, c9, 95,...)`

I have tried other methods on the statement: `getCharacterStream` for example, and it returns the same data.

It feels that this is a character encoding issue, but I don't know how to address it. It also feels that it might be something around the 'parameter style' which I have set to 'sql'. We have tried general as well and with that the 'iac' program also returns garbage.

I am in week two of this problem... we had a load of other issues in the RPG code which have been fixed, but for this one I am tearing my hair out.

Can anyone advise me how to get the data out of a stored procedure when the data is a 'clob'? If that is impossible, could you advice me how to get a large string (perhaps a megabyte) out of a stored procedure?

Tech stack:

- OS: Amazon Linux
- JDK 11
- JDBC library: net.sf.jt400/jt400-jdk9/10.6
- I am not sure what version of db2 is running on the IBMi: it's 'up to date' though

### Thanks!

Edited in to answer Charles question:

The rpg program starts like this. This is constantly being changed because we are experimenting with how to make the toJson have the correct CCSID. The two `/Set ccsid (*char : *UTF8)` are obviously not both needed. We've tried all four permutation (none/first/second/both).  This is the code that 'works' when we call the program from `IAC`.

```
**free
ctl-opt option(*srcStmt:*noDebugIO) dftactgrp(*no) actgrp('Somegroup') CCSID(*char:*jobRun);

exec SQL
  set option commit = *none;
/Set ccsid (*char : *UTF8)
  dcl-s toJsontemplate        sqltype(CLOB:10000000);
/restore CCSID(*char)

dcl-pi *n;
  fromJson  varChar(16000) ccsid(*utf8);
  /Set ccsid (*char : *UTF8)
  toJson        likeds(toJsontemplate);
  /restore CCSID(*char)
  id        packed(20);
  sha       varChar(20) ccsid(*utf8);
  version   varChar(20) ccsid(*utf8);
end-pi;
```

The place where the variable is set is looks like this

```
  exec SQL
   set :tojson = json_object(
       'returnStatus'            : trim(:returnStatus),
       'fetchKey'                : json_object(...
```

### Edit

Following the advice in the answers I used opt-ctl to set ccsid global.

```
**free
ctl-opt option(*srcStmt:*noDebugIO) dftactgrp(*no) actgrp('Somegroup') CCSID(*char:*UTF8);

exec SQL
  set option commit = *none;
  dcl-s toJsontemplate        sqltype(CLOB:10000000);

dcl-pi *n;
  fromJson  varChar(16000) ccsid(*utf8);
  toJson        likeds(toJsontemplate);
  id        packed(20);
  sha       varChar(20) ccsid(*utf8);
  version   varChar(20) ccsid(*utf8);
end-pi;
```

This made absolutely no difference. I think the variable tojson holds utf8 data (unless there is a bug in RPG) as opt-ctl sets the ccsid for the entire module. I think it is now clear (since the IAC can actually read the clob correctly) that this is some sort of negotiation issue between the Jdbc and the stored procedure. IAC does it properly and gets the correct data, and my code doesn't and gets the wrong data.

Any idea where I can go from here?

Comment: Do you have the same result if you use `values myclob5` from java ? and `values varchar(myclob5)` ?

Comment: Sure seems like a CCSID issue.  What does the PR/PI for the RPG program look like?  Does it's parameter definitions also have CCSID 1208?

Comment: Thanks @nfgl. I will write a program to do that tonight. (I can't easily modify the code to do that because values isn't a stored procedure).. Note that myclob5 is just us playing around in iac. It doesn't normally exist. We can of course add it if that works!

Comment: And thanks @Charles. I've edited the question to include the answer (too big to fit in here)

Comment: Have you tried using a DBCLOB with CCSID 1200 (UTF-16) instead of a CLOB?   That's a better fit for a Java caller since Java strings are stored internally as UTF-16.

Comment: @Jewberhard. Thank you for the suggestion. I hadn't and that's a good idea. My feeling is that there is 'something I am missing' a declartion somewhere, or a jdbc connection string or something. The code works when I call it from IAC / RunSqlScripts... so I sort of feel that the rpg is correct, and that the problem is somewhere in the jdbc connection

Comment: It looks like this is a known problem and IBM is working on fix.   Here is the APAR information:   https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/SE76152.   If you contact IBM i service, they may be able to get you a test PTF for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was much harder than expected. In the end I gave up doing it directly: I could not get the result from the clob into java in the manner I expected.

However 'there's always a way in IT'. So we ended up doing the same as we had working in IAC:

We used a global variable ('clob5' in this example). A global variable is defined in 'some library', [but each session gets it's own value](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=language-creating-using-global-variables) so we have no parallelism issues. The variable is defined once and then left alone

When we called the procedure in the stored procedure we use the same command we used

```
CALL ZZSP ('{"returnStatus":" ","fetchKey":{"inp1":1,"seq1":2},"status":"X"}',myClob5,?,?,?);
```

In order to get the value out of the variable we used **(using the same connection)**

```
SELECT myclob5 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I suspect you're doing something wrong with CCSID, but exactly what I can't tell.

What is the RPG program actually doing?  Is it really needed?  You might find it much easier to use an actual SQL Stored procedure (written in SQL).

If the RPG program is actually needed...

I question the use of the CCSID stuff in the first place.  Db2 for i and the JDBC driver have no issues converting from the EBCDIC CCSID into the UTF-16 used by Java.  Unless your input actually includes non-alphanumeric characters that only exist in Unicode.

Db2 for i and RPG are generally good at working with Unicode.  But a couple of old practices often cause problems.

1. Not setting a default CCSID for the system `dspsysval qccsid` It should be something other that 65535.
2. related, not having a CCSID set on the character columns in your tables `dspffd MYTABLE`
3. Jobs running under CCSID 65535, shouldn't be the case if the system is set to an actual default CCSID.

Assuming all those are good, I think coding

```
ctl-opt ccsid(*EXACT);
ctl-opt ccsid(*CHAR:*UTF8);
```

Would cause the RPG code to work with UTF-8 data across the board.  Db tables with columns as CCSID(37) would be converted to UTF-8 when read with native RPG file op-codes.

Here's a good [presentation](https://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Whats%20New%20and%20Exciting%20in%20RPG.pdf) about CCSID and RPG

**Edit**
The point about "questioning the need for the CCSID stuff" is that the Db/JDBC driver does quite well converting from EBCDIC to UTF-16 used by Java.  Particularly English ccsid(37) and the ASCII subset of Unicode.

Now you're dealing with 30+ countries, but the above holds true for most CCSIDs as far as I know without having actually been in that position.

However, JSON is supposed to be in UTF-8,UTF-16,UTF-32 so yeah the "right" thing to do would be to use Unicode parms.  But you'd need to use Unicode all the way down and back up the RPG call stack, otherwise you could run into unconvertable characters.

I've also never really looked into the RPG SQL Pre-Compiler functionality with respect to EBCDIC/Unicode conversion.

I suspect your

```
  exec SQL
   set :tojson = json_object(
       'returnStatus'            : trim(:returnStatus),
       'fetchKey'                : json_object(...
```

Is resulting in EBCDIC data in `tojson` that the system thinks is UTF-8, so it returns it as is.

Comment: The rpg program is allowing me to call another rpg program from a stored procedure. The actual rpg program I want to write is a legacy piece of code, and it has structures in its signature. this stored procedure turns the json in the input parameters into rpg variables, calls the original code, and then gets the result and turns that back into json. I don't know how to do that in sql (I've asked for help from RPG experts....which I am not).

Comment: Your comment about needing CCSID at all is interesting. I will explore that....  Your debug suggestions about things like `dspsysval ccsid`  is also helpful, but the IBMi is all set up correct, and in this case there isn't a table... I am watching the presentation now. Thanks for this... lots of places for me to explore now: I will see where I get to by Monday

Comment: To call an RPG program from SQL, all you need to do is define an External Stored Proc (just like you've done for program ZZSP).   Assuming the called RPG uses DS params or is otherwise not easily called directly, I can understand adding the ZZSP wrapper.  That being the case,  you may want to read the presentation and decide rather or not the wrapper should accepting UTF-8 and pay close attention to where the RPG code is converting data `ccsid(*LIST)`

Comment: @PhilRice don't assume "it's all set up correctly" ;)  Especially with long time users, not having a system CCSID set is very common.

Comment: Words of wisdom and experience there @Charles. Thank you. You are 100% correct: while the production machines are all set up correctly, the development machine I am using is set to 65535. I'll talk with the owners of the box on monday and decide what to do about that.

Comment: I'm reading your comment 'I question the use of ccsid in the first place'. Obviously some form for encoding is needing: unicode is just a mapping from numbers to letters... we need to pick an encoding so that we know how to serialise/deserialise the number. How would you do it? I should add that the code is going to run in over 30 countries and each IBMi will have it's own system ccsid if that impacts the advice (that's why we picked utf8...it's the same in every country now)

Comment: thanks for the edit. I suspect you are right about the cause (the system thinking it is UTF9 already). The data I have is created in this program though: it's the bottom of the stack and I do have full control over it. I thought I'd made everything utf8, but having read that presentation I will be using the `opt-ctl` option to make sure.  The 'thing that is doing my head in' is that I can access the stored procedure using IAC and get the right idea. That makes we wonder if it is a negotation thing between java and db2.... I'll play on monday and we'll see!

Comment: I experimented with the ccsid settings (thanks for the presentation) and it makes no difference. I edited the question to show the new rpg source code. There's no 'stack' further down... this is all there is.